# Register deserializer for a wrapped List of type

Tags: jackson, kotlin, jackson-modules

I have JSON that is like this:

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

And for example say the `Application` class looks like this

```
data class Application(
    val id: String
)
```

I want to deserialize the JSON into a `List<Application>`, where each `{...}` is an `Application`. I was hoping to do this without having to create a wrapper class like `Applications`, annotating it with `@JsonRootName`, and then enabling `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`. The end goal is to have a [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) interface that has something like:

```
@GET("api/apps")
fun listApplications(): Call<List<Application>>
```

I tried to implement a simple `JsonDeserializer` (could probably be optimized):

```
class ApplicationListDeserializer
  : JsonDeserializer<List<Application>>() {

  companion object {
    private val COLLECTION_TYPE: CollectionType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
        .constructCollectionType(List::class.java, Application::class.java)
  }
  override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): List<Application> {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val node: JsonNode = parser.codec.readTree(parser)
    val collectionReader = mapper.readerFor(COLLECTION_TYPE)
    return collectionReader.readValue(node.get("apps"))
  }
}
```

I don't see any way to register this deserializer for this specific type. I tried this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
val module = SimpleModule()
module.addDeserializer(List::class.java, ApplicationListDeserializer())
objectMapper.registerModule(module)
val applications: List<Application> = objectMapper.readValue("""{
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": "/api-catalog-backend"
    }
  ]
}""")
```

But that fails with:

```
Can not construct instance of Application: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)&#xa; at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])" type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException"><![CDATA[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of Application: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012)
```

I am using the following dependency versions:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-core", "2.8.6")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-kotlin", "2.8.4")
compile(kotlinModule("stdlib", "1.1-M03"))
compile(kotlinModule("reflect", "1.1-M03"))
```

How do I configure the deserialization to work correctly with a `List<Application>`?